# Is "modificate" an English word?

Tags: verbs, is-it-a-word

Is "modificate" a correct English word?

From source: http://www.definitions.net/definition/modificate (Webster Dictionary)

> **Modificate** *(verb)*
>
> to qualify
>
> **Origin:** [See Modify.]

But if I look in the Cambridge dictionary, it returns nothing: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=Modificate

Comment: Yes, it's listed in the 1913 edition of Webster's, but [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/modificate) gets it right here: _obsolete_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be an obsolete usage of Latin origin (modificare)     “*to limit, measure off, restrain," from modus "measure, manner*", probably used mainly in formal  contexts:

[Modificate](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/modificate):

> (obsolete) To qualify.
>
> John Pearson, Bishop of Chester
>
> - The kingdoms of this world are become the kingdoms of the Lord, and of his Christ, and he shall reign for ever and ever, not only to the modificated eternity of his Mediatorship, so long as there shall be need of regal power to subdue the enemies of God's Elect; but also to the complete eternity of the duration of his Humanity, which for the future is co-eternal to his Divinity.

(Wiktionary)